# Java: Arrays, what is happening here?

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote the program below to play around with arrays.

```
    public class Tester{
    public static void main (String[]args){
      int [] nums = {1,3,6,1,2};

      System.out.println(nums[0]);  
      System.out.println(nums[nums[1]]);  
   }
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
```

What is happening in the second print statement? I still can't figure it out. If I switch the [1] with 6 or 2, I get an error but not 3.

Comment: nums[1] is 3. now you take the value 3 as parameter for nums[]. nums[3] is also 1 just as nums[0]

Comment: what so strange there ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nums[1]` equals 3, and `nums[3]` equals 1, so your second line prints the line that has the index which value is stored in  `nums[1]`, which is 3.

```
nums[0] = 1;
nums[1] = 3;
nums[2] = 6;
nums[3] = 1; <-- nums[nums[1]]
nums[4] = 2;
```

You are getting an error with `System.out.println(nums[nums[6]]);` because you are accessing to a position out of the range of the array. The same happen with `System.out.println(nums[nums[2]]);` because nums[2] = 6.

Comment: nums[4] is 2 not 1

Comment: I added some information to your answer feel free to removed it or to changed it into your own words.